# Long start up for: systemd-backlight@backlight:nvidia_0.service

Tags: startup, backlight, user-space

I am new to Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS) and am attempting to decrease my start up time on my Predator laptop. There are a number of different areas I could target to decrease the start-up time, but for this post I am specifically looking to either remove the systemd-backlight@blacklight: nvidia_0.service or somehow find a way to decrease the amount of time it requires.

Command:

```
systemd-analyze time
```

Terminal output:

```
Startup finished in 8.657s (firmware) + 5.337s (loader) + 6.317s (kernel) + 50.222s (userspace) = 1min 10.534s 
graphical.target reached after 50.181s in userspace
```

Command:

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

Terminal output:

```
graphical.target @50.181s
└─multi-user.target @50.181s
  └─kerneloops.service @32.422s +137ms
    └─network-online.target @32.358s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @22.837s +9.519s
        └─NetworkManager.service @17.817s +5.015s
          └─dbus.service @17.809s
            └─basic.target @17.659s
              └─sockets.target @17.658s
                └─snapd.socket @17.641s +8ms
                  └─sysinit.target @17.494s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:nvidia_0.service @37.488s +36ms
                      └─nvidia-persistenced.service @18.228s +1.360s
                        └─basic.target @17.659s
                          └─...
```

I've tried searching the web, and all I could find was [this site](https://systemd.network/systemd-backlight.html).

> systemd-backlight understands the following kernel command line parameter:

> systemd.restore_state=

> Takes a boolean argument. Defaults to "1". If "0", does not restore the backlight settings on boot. However, settings will still be stored on shutdown.

My best guess was to open my Terminal and enter

`systemd.restore_state=0`

But I received:

```
systemd.restore_state=: command not found
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand "ms" stands for miliseconds? As in 1/1000 of a second. Are you really worried about 36/1000 secs?

Answer (score 0):

I guess setting it as a bootparameter in GRUB is different to just entering it in the terminal afterwards.

On Fedora 36 setting systemd.restore_state=0 resolved a hang on "starting systemd-backlight@blacklight: nvidia_0.service"
I could finally boot again, thanks for your question and the additional information!

Comment: Do you know this works for Ubuntu?